# Redux state not updating, despite all data being passed around correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Tearing my hair out on this one, and I'm sure it'll be a stupid oversight but I've spent hours on it now!

I'm using the action creators and reducers below. Everything seems to work (I've run a `console.log` at every stage in the process and the data is being passed around correctly) but for some reason my store state is not updating.

The initial state is being set correctly when the page loads, so it's just when I pass data in through the action later on - nothing happens!

Can anyone spot the error? Thanks!

displayMessage.js (action)

```
export default function displayMessage(type, message){
    return {
        type: 'DISPLAY_MESSAGE',
        payload: {
            status: type,
            message: message
        }
    }
}
```

reducer_displayMessage.js

```
const initialState = {
    status: '',
    message: ''
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'DISPLAY_MESSAGE':
            return action.payload;
    }
    return state;
}
```

rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import SlideOverReducer from './reducer_slideOver';
import WorkshopSelectReducer from './reducer_workshopSelection';
import UserDetailsReducer from './reducer_userDetails';
import QualDetailsReducer from './reducer_qualDetails';
import DisplayMessageReducer from './reducer_displayMessage';

export default combineReducers({
    slideOver: SlideOverReducer,
    workshopSelection: WorkshopSelectReducer,
    userDetails: UserDetailsReducer,
    qualDetails: QualDetailsReducer,
    displayMessage: DisplayMessageReducer
});
```

EDIT: And here's one of the components that should use this action:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from '../../cssPartials/slideOverBar.css';
import tableStyles from '../../cssPartials/formElements.css';
import newUser from '../../../../data/actions/newUser';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import actions from '../../../../data/actions/actions';

class NewUser extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            type: null,
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: ''
        }
    }

    //...Other methods      

    submitForm(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const firstName = this.state.firstName;
        const lastName = this.state.lastName;
        const email = this.state.email;
        const type = this.state.type;

        newUser(firstName, lastName, email, type, (data) => {
            const displayType = data.success ? 'success' : 'error'
            this.props.displayMessage(displayType, data.message) //Redux dispatch is called here
        });

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <form className={styles.formElement}>
                    <div className={`btn-group btn-group-justified`}>
                        <div className={`btn-group`}>
                            <button className={this.state.type === 'admin' ? `btn btn-default active` : `btn btn-default`}
                                    onClick={(e) => this.chooseType(e, 'admin')}>Admin</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className={`btn-group`}>
                            <button className={this.state.type === 'tutor' ? `btn btn-default active` : `btn btn-default`}
                                    onClick={(e) => this.chooseType(e, 'tutor')}>Tutor</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {
                        this.state.type !== null 
                            ? <div className={styles.spacer}>
                                <input 
                                     type='text'
                                     className={tableStyles.input}
                                     value={this.state.firstName}
                                     placeholder='Enter first name'
                                     onChange={(e) => this.enterName(e, 'first')} />
                              </div>
                            : null

                    }
                    {
                            this.state.type !== null && this.state.firstName.length > 0
                                ? <div className={styles.spacer}>
                                    <input 
                                         type='text'
                                         className={tableStyles.input}
                                         value={this.state.lastName}
                                         placeholder='Enter last name'
                                         onChange={(e) => this.enterName(e, 'last')} />
                                  </div>
                                : null
                    }
                    {
                        this.state.type !== null && this.state.firstName.length > 0 && this.state.lastName.length > 0
                            ? <div className={styles.spacer}>
                                <input type='email'
                                     className={tableStyles.input}
                                     value={this.state.email}
                                     placeholder='Enter e-mail'
                                     onChange={(e) => this.enterEmail(e)} />
                              </div>
                            : null
                    }

                    {
                        this.state.type !== null && this.state.firstName.length > 0 && this.state.lastName.length > 0 && this.state.email.length > 7
                            ? <div className={styles.spacer}>
                                <div className={`btn-group btn-group-justified`}>
                                    <div className={`btn-group`}>
                                        <button type='submit' className={`btn btn-primary`} onClick={(e) => this.submitForm(e)} >Create User Account</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            : null


                    }

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({ displayMessage: actions.displayMessage }, dispatch)
}


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NewUser);
```

Comment: Without knowing how you're mapping the state to props it's hard to say. What are you seeing in the Redux devtools?

Comment: Can you post the component that is using this?

Comment: Are you sure you are dispatching the action with `this.dispatch()` and not just calling the action creator `displayMessage()`?

Comment: I'm using the react-redux library to map the dispatch to props - will edit to show

Comment: Incidentally, the `newUser()` method in which `this.props.displayMessage()` is called is an ajax call to write the new user info to the database. The callback is supposed to get the returned data and put it into a pop up message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it looks like there isn't actually any problem at all!

For some reason, the store state shown in the React Developer tools was not updating straight away - when I triggered a separate event which called a different action, the state for this action updated as well.

I don't understand why it isn't showing immediately - other changes to the state do - but I've tested it with a dummy component that relies on changes to the store state and it seems to work fine.

So apologies to all - it seems as though this was a non-issue - but it boils down to a bit of strange behaviour in the developer tools rather than an actual problem!

Comment: The React devtools show component state. The Redux devtools show the actions and state changes to the Redux state. When you use redux-react you're mapping Redux state to component *properties*, not *state*.

Answer (score 0):

in `displayMessage`, you need to do this.dispatch({type and value...}) To say to your reducer: "Hey man, here's new stuff for you!"